# Can I rewire an audio amplifier with a round pin plug to fit sockets in living room made for lamps?

Tags: electrical, wiring, appliances

Basically I just bought a home theatre system but our living room has 2 round pin 5amp plugs that are locaed where I would like the amp and rear speakers. Can I wire a round pin 5 amp plug onto the amp and use the round pin sockets? Or does an adapter exist that I could use? (UK)

Amplifier details below.

TA-SA500WR/TA-SA600WR:
POWER OUTPUT (reference)
Surround L/Surround R:
200 W (per channel at 6 ohms, 1 kHz)
TA-SA700WR:
POWER OUTPUT (reference)
Surround L/Surround R:
 100 W (per channel at 6 ohms, 1 kHz)
Rated impedance
6 
Communication system
Wireless sound Specification version
3.0
Frequency band
Europe, Oceania, Africa*, India, Middle
East*, Thailand, and Russia models:
5.2 GHz, 5.8 GHz
Singapore and Taiwan models:
5.8 GHz
China model: 5.2 GHz
* 5.2 GHz or 5.8 GHz may not be
available in some countries/regions.
Modulation method
DSSS
Power requirements
220 V – 240 V AC, 50/60 Hz

Comment: Asking if a plug could be rewired really needs the plug type or a photo. Without that info all the amplifier details are useless.

Comment: In the context of UK electrics "round pin plug" means BS546.

Comment: Wow, all that and you left out the one thing that matters, the amps input off the nameplate.  It may be *actually on the nameplate*, not in the PDF specs, because sometimes vendors are really obtuse about including that in the spec sheet for UL listing reasons.

Comment: Can you post a photo of the nameplate please?

Comment: I found a copy of the service manual at https://servlib.com/sony/audio/ta-sa500wr-ta-sa600wr-ta-sa700wr.html , it seems to be self-contradictory though listing audio power output levels much higher than the power consumption levels. I suspect that is a case of the audio power output levels being rated under a stupid rating scheme and that the "power consumption" figure is the accurate one.

Answer (score 3):

> Can I wire a round pin 5 amp plug onto the amp

Nothing stops you from doing so.

> Or does an adapter exist

Yes, adapters exist, they are sold as travel adapters for people from the UK who are visiting India (the indian 6A plug is equivilent to the 5A BS546).

Unfortunately many travel adapters are frankly complete garbage. I belive https://www.amazon.co.uk/Go-Travel-Earthed-Compact-Convertor/dp/B079VRTCRX is a non-garbage one but I haven't bought one personally.

---

Be aware that 5A sockets found in a domestic premesis will almost certainly be fed from a lighting circuit. So pay attention to total load on said circuit. They will also likely be fed via a light switch, people may find it confusing if the hi-fi turns off when they turn off the light switches.

Also make sure the socket is not fed via a dimmer. If it is then you would need to change the dimmer for a conventional switch before plugging anything other than dimmer-compatible lighting into it.